# Google Cloud DNS records do not propagate to any server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Hej!

I own a domain registered through GCP and it's connected with Cloud DNS in GCP, I would be very happy if you could help me setup my custom domain for my web page at [buahaha.github.io](https://buahaha.github.io).

I think I know how to do this, because I did it before with other domain(s), but this time something is not working as it should. I have set up even a TXT record, and it does not propagate through DNS servers, and the same goes for my CNAME record. I attach screenshots of my setup below.

[image: GCP Cloud DNS setup]

[image: dig command]

It's strange to me as it is the basic setup for this kind of service, and I'm really confused...

Pozdrawiam,
Szymon

Comment: What are the NS (name server) records at the registrar? The NS records in your post do not match: `ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com`.

Comment: Thank you John for pointing this out. In fact it's true what you said. The name server is setup with all the servers with `c` prefix. I've changed that.

Comment: Be careful what you change and where. The registrar controls the name servers, not the NS entry in the child's DNS server.

Comment: I agree with @john hanley your screenshot in cloud dns shows a different NS from dig. No record will work in that zone since it is not the registrars NS. Just wondering is this already resolved?

Comment: I have found the issue. In GCP Cloud Domains, there is an option to set the DNS settings. I had to choose my Cloud DNS zone to use with my domain.

Comment: Thank you for your input and hoping solving the problem. My page is live on custom domain. I hope this post will help also somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @blacha answer, here are some links and guidance. Once you use [Cloud Domain](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/register-domain#registering-a-domain) to register a domain, there is an option where you can use which DNS provider that you use for your domain. These are Cloud DNS, Google Domains and Custom Name servers.

If by chance you get confused which DNS server that you are using I suggest to [DIG](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/) your domain to see which name server that you are using just to make sure you are using the correct DNS server.

Since this concern choses Cloud DNS here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/set-up-dns-records-domain-name) that you can follow on how to create zone, configure A record connecting to the domains IP address and creating Cname record for the subdomain that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had to explicitly choose Cloud DNS as my DNS provider. If you have set your DNS zone already, just choose it from the drop-down menu, otherwise create your own...

[image]